# PHP not loading ENV vars set in /etc/sysconfig/httpd

Tags: php, apache

I am running Drupal sites (Apache and PHP), and would like to set some of the values in the settings files to be environment variables.  After researching, the proper approach appears to be adding them into the /etc/sysconfig/httpd file.  It appears that PHP (mod_php) is not loading the variables.

My /etc/sysconfig/httpd file looks like this -

```
LANG=C
db_server=internaldns.mine.com
db_port=3306
memcache_server1=otherinternaldns.mine.com:11211
```

I am loading the variables in Drupal (which is php 7 (mod_php)) like this -

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
   ...
  'host' => $_ENV['db_server'],
  'port' => $_ENV['db_port'],
   ...
);
```

However, it doesn't appear to be loading the variables, as when I do a status of the site, I see the following -

```
 Drupal version : 8.9.11                                                                             
 Site URI       : http://default                                                                     
 DB driver      : mysql                                                                              
 DB port        :              (THIS SHOULD HAVE THE VARIABLE)
```

When I set the same values without variables they work normally.

Is there some step I am missing here for getting the variable loaded inside of the env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who encounters something similar:

Even though the variables were set in the /etc/sysconfig/httpd file, they were not being imported into my Shell (but PHP was importing them correctly).

After creating a file in /etc/profile.d/ that exported the variables for the shell, it worked on the cmd line as well -

```
#!/bin/bash

# DB Vars
export db_server=db_server
export db_port=3306
```

As a note - Even though it looked like a failure on the CMD line before these variables were exported, the website was being served successfully by httpd.  This implied that PHP was using the variables correctly.